# Laravel 5.1 hasMany relation query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1, has-many

I'm trying to develop a simple web-app where I store a farmer's detail and his/her cultivation information.

I have 2 database tables - `farmer` and `farmer_crop`.

```
farmer table
id | name | phone

farmer_crop table
id | farmer_id | farming_location | farming_crop_name | harvest_end_date
```

I made 2 controllers - `FarmerController` & `FarmerCropController`. A Farmer can cultivate many crops so the Farmer has `hasMany`  with FarmerCrop. Now I want to show a list of farmers using the `FarmerController`'s index method where I get farmers who are farming wheat. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: Just to be sure, do you need Eloquent solution or raw mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use something like.

```
class = FarmerController extends Controller

public function index()
{
    $results = FarmerCrop::with('farmers')
               ->where('farming_crop_name', 'wheat')
               ->get();

    return view('farms.crops', compact('results'));
}
```

I don't know the name of your models so best guess above..

#### Update after comment

In that case you would just add an additional were clause.Ezequiel was alos correct with his answer. But I will modify his and add in your new requirements.

```
$farmers = App\Farmer::with(['crops' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('farming_crop_name', 'wheat');
}])
->where('user_type_id', 3)
->get();
```

Comment: This query will  return Farmercrops with farmers as a field. This is not what OP asked.

Comment: actually my main app is too big, i just explained it in a nutshell so that i can get some ideas. in real there is no farmers table. i have table called User. there are 3 types of user. Admin, Agent and Farmer. Where Farmer is user_type_id = 3. Model Names are User.php ,  FarmerCrop.php. first i need to filter my farmers from the users table and then i have to search in the farmer_crop table if he is cultivating any crop or not. if he is cultivating any crop(like wheat) then i will return his name, so what will be the code? @lee

Comment: See update. But it you want it with or without crops you could add a OR statement as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
$farmers = App\Farmer::with(['crops' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('farming_crop_name', '=', 'wheat');
}])->get();
```